# Is it possible to reverse the position of the number and emoji keyboards?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, keyboard

On my iPhone, the emoji keyboard is to the right of the number keyboard:
[image]

On my iPad, it’s on the left:
[image]

Due to muscle memory, every time I’m typing on my iPad I bring up the emoji keyboard in error. I won’t ask anyone to explain why Apple have been inconsistent here, but is there a way to reverse them? I’ve tried removing and re-adding the emoji keyboard in settings, but that didn’t work.

Comment: I see this on my iPhone 6S. It changes whether I'm in portrait or landscape, which is infuriating. I checked an iPad Mini [same iOS]... it stays the same as your top image in both orientations. Inconsistent :/

Comment: @Tetsujin it stays in the same position for me on both devices, regardless of orientation. Both are running the iOS 12 beta so that might be why.

Comment: ah - I haven't seen iOS 12 beta. Personally if it picked one & stuck to it I wouldn't care which; eventually I'd get used to it. It's the inconsistency that drives me mad. Bug report it - it may not be too late. I've had Mojave bugs I reported fixed in the past couple of weeks. It IS possible ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did file this as a bug during the beta testing of iOS 12, but I'm fairly sure it still remained a problem in the final release. However, my iPad is running iOS 12.1 beta and the keyboard now matches my iPhone:

[image]

Comment: The fix is available for everybody now: https://www.macstories.net/news/apple-releases-bug-fix-update-to-ios-12/